# wxPython: Problem with text selection using TextEditMixin

Tags: wxpython, selection, highlight, listctrl

I have an issue when editing cells in a wxListCtrl using the TextEditMixin.  The first time editing a cell, the selected text highlights fine.  However, on subsequent attempts to edit cells the selected text does not highlight.

The text is apparently selected as it can be moved, deleted, replaced;  it's just that the highlighting feedback does not appear on second and subsequent cell edits.

Python: 3.7;  wxWidgets: 4.0.7post2;  OS: Windows 10 pro and LTSC 1809

Thoughts?

Here is code that can be run to demonstrate the problem:

```
# example showing TextEditMixin issue: not highlighting selecting text
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix

class ListCtrlCustom(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)


class ListCtrlPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # create the list with ability to edit cells
        self.list_ctrl = ListCtrlCustom(self, size=(-1, 100), style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        #self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_EDIT_LABELS | wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "col 1", width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "col 2", width=100)

        # add rows to the list
        for idx in range(0, 2):
            colOneText = 'col1 value: ' + str(idx)
            colTwoText = 'col2 value: ' + str(idx)
            self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(idx, colOneText)
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(idx, 1, colTwoText)

        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class ListCtrlFrame(wx.Frame, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='list ctrl test')
        self.panel = ListCtrlPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = ListCtrlFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It works on my Ubuntu/Mint box, perhaps you should state your platform and see if anyone with that Operating system can help. It may even be related to the Theme you are running on your desktop. Try a few others to test it.

Comment: Thanks for checking Rolf.  I've added my platform to the question (win10) and tried a couple of other themes - same behaviour.